# Cauchy Integral Formula (what to do when singularities are on the boundary?)

Tags: complex-analysis

$\oint_{|z + 1| = 3}\frac{e^{z^2}}{(z-2)^2}dx$

It looks like the singularity here is on the boundary.  I'm not sure if this is considered "inside" the contour or not.

Comment: You'll need to deform that contour to either enclose the pole or exclude it.  The result is a Cauchy Principal Value.

Comment: It makes sense to consider the average of the results you get by considering $z=2$ inside the integration path and outside.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the average of zero and some other value?

Comment: Are you sure it's $dx$ and not $dz$?

Comment: @NażysławZbyłutowicz: exactly, i.e. $\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{e^{z^2}}{(z-2)^2},z=2\right)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, you're right, I meant $dz$